# 'Failed to connect: no buffer space' when curlPerform attempted

Tags: r

I'm sending a curlPerform with curl.opts set to

```
curl.opts = curlOptions(
  httpheader = c(
    'Content-Type'    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    'Accept'          = "application/json"
  ),
  verbose = FALSE,
  header = TRUE,
  useragent = "RCurl"    
)
```

and I eventually get the error "failed to connect to 192.168.141.136: no buffer space".
I need to run this program constantly for days but this happens after about 6 minutes.
Is there a way to set the buffer maximum higher?
Alternatively, is there a way to view how much "buffer space" is remaining? If so I can set it to restart R and resume the program.
Note that this happens if the program runs for a while, stops, and I manually restart it. The "buffer" is never being cleared. The only way to clear it that I've found is to restart R.

If it helps, I also lose my "connection" with Rstudio, even if I'm just doing this with a separate R window, and I also lose my connection to the internet after getting this error until I close R

edit: here is a partial result of traceback() (the rest isn't a problem)

```
11: fun(structure(list(message = msg, call = sys.call()), class = c(typeName, 
        "GenericCurlError", "error", "condition")))
10: function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) 
    {
        if (!is.character(type)) {
            i = match(type, CURLcodeValues)
            typeName = if (is.na(i)) 
                character()
            else names(CURLcodeValues)[i]
        }
        typeName = gsub("^CURLE_", "", typeName)
        fun = (if (asError) 
            stop
        else warning)
        fun(structure(list(message = msg, call = sys.call()), class = c(typeName, 
            "GenericCurlError", "error", "condition")))
    }(7L, "Failed to connect to 192.168.141.136: No buffer space", 
        TRUE)
9: .Call("R_curl_easy_perform", curl, .opts, isProtected, .encoding, 
       PACKAGE = "RCurl")
8: curlPerform(url = "http://gt-tradeview/House/TradeView/ajax/varys", 
       postfields = mkURL(parameters), .opts = curl.opts, writefunction = r$update, 
       post = 1L, curl = r$curl()) at functiondefinitionsLive.R#211
7: value[[3L]](cond)
6: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more details - at least what request are you performing, but ideally a fully reproducible example. The  error appears to be coming from curl, so you can also try googling "no buffer space curl"

Comment: something reproducible isn't possible because its requesting data from a server my company has, not the internet. Google has not been helpful.
However, I found that `getCurlOptionsConstants()['buffersize'] `returns `98.`
unfortunately, although `curlOptions(buffersize = 1000000000)` returns `$buffersize
[1] 1000000000

attr(,"class")
[1] "CURLOptions"`
nothing really changes.
There are a lot of possible commands under `apropos("curl") but I don't know where to start...

Comment: Then you need to recreate the problem using a public server. Given the rarity of the problem, something unusual is going on.

Comment: changing to 
`,
  verbose = FALSE,
  header = TRUE,
  buffersize = 100000000,
  useragent = "RCurl"
)`
doesn't help either fwiw

Comment: buffer space running out doesn't seem like the most unusual problem. If I could even find out where the currently used buffer space is being displayed I could easily fix this. (I'm using RExcel so I can restart R on demand, but without seeing the buffer I'd have to make it restart with a really high frequency to catch all cases, instead of checking the buffer directly)
Rexcel doesn't need to be used btw, I'm running this program without it for now to be sure.

Comment: It _is_ unusual - if you google for "curl no buffer space", you'll see that very few other people have encountered it.

Comment: Here'sa possibility, [the WSAPoll Windows API call is broken](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/)--which version of cURL are you using?

Comment: $version
[1] "7.19.7"

$vesion_num
[1] 463623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that handles were being reserved with every call, and never closed. To prevent this, get a curl handle with `getCurlHandle()` then pass that with the `curl` argument in `dynCurlReader()`

Comment: Isn't that done automatically? `getCurlHandle()` is the default value for the `curl` argument. Just asking because I'm struggling with the same issue and this didn't solve it for me.

Comment: yes, which calls getCurlHandle() every time you run the function. Instead, set `curlVar  <- getCurlHandle()` somewhere where it'll only be run once, then `dynCurlReader(curl = curlVar)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues with the getURL command. I tried CloseAllConnections() but that did not seem to work.

When I restarted the R session then the issue was resolved automatically. However, I have to admit that I got the issue when my RStudio  ( R Session ) was opened for a long time. Might be some memory usage that an empty R Session does